# Customize magento2 default footer links

Tags: magento2, php

I just installed magento2 website, what I want to do is to add "About Us" footer link into the default footer links, from search, what I can achieve is to 
1) Create a block
2) Create a widget, then set the widget for all pages, for the footer links
Below is what I have completed, but I want to insert the "About Us" directly below the default "Contact Us", is that possible for magento 2?
[image]

And I am still not know how magento2 generates the default footer links, I cannot figure out from the theme default.xml (/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout)

```
     <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
        <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
            <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

Does anybody have insight? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new custom theme in your magento site - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

and add this below code to theme **default.xml** in layout folder

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="footer_links">            
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="about-us" after="contact-us-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">About Us</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">link-to-about-us</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

If you don't know how to create a theme then insert the code in the file you mentioned above after the referenceContainer tag. But it not preferable

Note : after the theme creation you need to run **bin/magento setup:content-deploy** and clear cache